# Which version of searchlogic works with Rails 2.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I just installed searchlogic 2.4.24 for my Rails 2.1.0 app but got the following error :-

..aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method':NameError: undefined method`merge_joins' for class `Class'

Is it a version conflict? Does anyone know which version of searchlogic works with Rails 2.1.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could give searchlogic < 2.0 a go (2.0 introduced a complete rewrite), but I'd rather suggest trying to bump up to Rails 2.3 or at least 2.2 and take it from there.

Comment: thanks stuart! I needed the column_like_any method alone from searchlogic. figured its better to write my own method than update Rails for now :). I will eventually have to get around to the update though, cos I'll need more from searchlogic in the future for sure.